# Uploading a Large Dataset(10 GB+) into Jupyter Notebooks/GCP AI Notebooks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

**TL;DR:**

*How to move a large dataset(over 30 GB) from BigQuery to Jupyter Notebooks(AI Notebook within GCP)*

**Problem:**

I do have a  ~ 30GB dataset(time series) that I want to upload to Jupyter Notebooks(AI Notebook) in order to test a NN model before deploying it in its own server. The dataset already has been built in Bigquery, and I did move it  using wildcards(100 parts) into Storage.

**What I have done:**

However, I am stuck trying to upload it into the Notebook:

1) Bigquery does not allow to query it directly, also too slow

2) Can not download it and the upload locally

2) Did move it to the storage in avro format, but have not achived to query it using the wildcards:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from io import BytesIO
client = storage.Client()

bucket = "xxxxx"
file_path = "path"

blob = storage.blob.Blob(file_path,bucket)

content = blob.download_as_string()

train = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(content))
```

What I am missing? Should I make the model into a function and the using Dataflow somehow?

Best

Comment: Can you try following this article? https://medium.com/google-cloud/datalab-bigquery-fast-dataset-queries-to-build-image-file-repository-857ec94275ae

Comment: Were you able to download it? I am having a similar problem, except its a 70+ GB file on Google Drive (shared file) I have tried some stuff on the internet, but not able to solve it. 

Link to file: https://ict.fbk.eu/must-c-release-v2-0/